# Aspose HTML to RTF conversion adds blank list element

Tags: html, aspose, file-conversion, aspose.words

I am using Aspose for conversion from html to rtf in system. And if html have ordered / unordered list element with no value, Aspose adds one more blank list element in result file.

I filed ticket with Aspose but I wanted to know if anyone had this problem before and found any solution or work around already?

**htmlString**

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div>
   Hellow 1 become 2,
  </div> 
  <div></div> 
  <ol> 
   <li></li> 
  </ol> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Here is my logic for conversion of this string to rtf

```
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        Document doc = new Document(is);

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        com.aspose.words.SaveOptions saveOptions = com.aspose.words.SaveOptions.createSaveOptions(SaveFormat.RTF);
        saveOptions.setSaveFormat(SaveFormat.RTF);
        doc.save(os, saveOptions);


        rtfString = new String(os.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

And result rtf looks like this [Result Rtf File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IRV4.png)

Comment: We have already logged this issue with ID WORDSNET-18009. This issue is currently pending for analysis and is in the queue. We will inform you as soon as this issue is resolved or any workaround is available. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez Thank you, do you have any update for this issue? Customers are getting furious because of this issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your issue is currently ‘pending for analysis’ and is in the queue. We will inform you via this thread as soon as this issue is resolved. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Comment: The issue you had found earlier (filed as WORDSNET-18009) has now been fixed in [this Aspose.Words for .NET 19.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Aspose.Words/19.3.0) update and [this Aspose.Words for Java 19.3](https://repository.aspose.com/repo/com/aspose/aspose-words/19.3/) update. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: @AwaisHafeez Thank you for update. Appreciate it.